Visual Studio 2022 C# is it possible to set richTextBox to scroll vertical with text (and vertical scrollbars are enabled)
Visual Studio 2022 C#: is it possible to set richTextBox to scroll vertically when text is entered?
I use a richtextbox as a sort of terminal (aka DOS window) and have enabled vertical scrollbars. However I do not have any event code when e.g. text input exceeds the height of the box. I would like to trigger the scrollbars position to scroll "back" in time when e.g. listing files.
When I add text e.g. list files, I would like it to scroll text up. Instead I need to move the scrollbars to see text outside the window.
